# Resize background image same as page width and height in tcpdf with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, resize, scale, tcpdf

I am trying to create a pdf with background image . It is not resizing up to page width and height.This is the code i used.

```
$pdf->setImageScale(1.53);
$pdf->AddPage();
$width = $pdf->getPageWidth();
$height = $pdf->getPageHeight();
$pdf->Image($img_file, 0, 0, $width, $height, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the page width and height first then storing it in a var and calling the var in your script?

Comment: I tried it already

Answer (score 2):

Use the following option:

`$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);`